# Taylor approximation

Tags: signal-processing

Suppose we're given the position  \$x\$ , velocity  \$\dot{x}\$ , and acceleration \$\ddot{x}\$ at \$t_1 \$.

We need to approximate the position \$x\$ at \$t_2\$.

In below picture, I understand how \$x_1\$  represents the vertical black length, and how  \$ \color{blue}{\dot{x_1}(t_1)}h\$ represents the vertical blue length. However I don't get how \$\color{green}{\ddot{x}(t_1)}\dfrac{h^2}{2}\$ represents the green length. I'm wondering if there a simple derivation for proving that the green vertical length equals \$\color{green}{\ddot{x}(t_1)}\dfrac{h^2}{2}\$ . Any ideas ? Thanks !
[image]

Comment: This question is from signals and systems, but I completely understand if this question belongs in math and I'll gladly post it in math if you think so.. (I got so used to electronics page that I didn't realize this till after finishing composing the q..)

Comment: I think this is indeed better suited to Math SE. I'm usually not too strict on this type of stuff, but I believe the connection to electronics is too weak for this question ;-)

Comment: Integral of h is.......?

Comment: @Andyaka Integral of h is h^2/2. That quadratic is what we get by integrating x''(t) = c.  I now see clearly how the taylor quadratic looks geometrically. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Is \$\dot{x}\$ derivative of x ?

Comment: Yes @LongPham if I recall correctly, physicists use \$\dot{x}\$ to represent derivative of \$x\$ with respect to *time*, and mathematicians use \$x'\$... Not sure about engineers hmm

Answer (score 2):

It is the contribution of the constant acceleration **a**.

After **h** time, the speed will have increased by **ah**. So the average extra speed over **h** will be **ah/2**. The extra distance due to that average extra speed will then be **h*(ah)/2**.

Which is the same as

$$ ah^2/2 $$

Comment: Ah so \$ah^2/2\$ is \$a(t_2-t_1)^2/2\$, and this term is part of the whole quadratic \$x(t_1) + x'(t_1)(t_2-t_1) + x''(t_1)(t_2-t_1)^2/2\$ . I see... that average acceleration interpretation is clever! Can we interpret something similar for the fourth term too ? \$ah^3/6\$

Comment: Yeah, it's called [jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics))